# Why doesn't 1 + 1 use BINARY_ADD?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-internals

I do this:

```
>>> dis.dis(lambda: 1 + 1)
0 LOAD_CONST        2 (2)
3 RETURN_VALUE
```

I was expecting a BINARY_ADD opcode to perform the addition. How was the sum computed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the work of Python's peephole optimizer. It evaluates simple operations with only constants during the compile time itself and stores the result as a constant in the generated bytecode.

Quoting from the [Python 2.7.9 Source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/648dcafa7e5f/Python/peephole.c#l472),

```c
            /* Fold binary ops on constants.
               LOAD_CONST c1 LOAD_CONST c2 BINOP -->  LOAD_CONST binop(c1,c2) */
        case BINARY_POWER:
        case BINARY_MULTIPLY:
        case BINARY_TRUE_DIVIDE:
        case BINARY_FLOOR_DIVIDE:
        case BINARY_MODULO:
        case BINARY_ADD:
        case BINARY_SUBTRACT:
        case BINARY_SUBSCR:
        case BINARY_LSHIFT:
        case BINARY_RSHIFT:
        case BINARY_AND:
        case BINARY_XOR:
        case BINARY_OR:
            if (lastlc >= 2 &&
                ISBASICBLOCK(blocks, i-6, 7) &&
                fold_binops_on_constants(&codestr[i-6], consts)) {
                i -= 2;
                assert(codestr[i] == LOAD_CONST);
                cumlc = 1;
            }
            break;
```

Basically, it looks for instructions like this

```
LOAD_CONST c1
LOAD_CONST c2
BINARY_OPERATION
```

and evaluates that and replaces those instructions with the result and a `LOAD_CONST` instruction. Quoting the [comment in the `fold_binops_on_constants` function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/648dcafa7e5f/Python/peephole.c#l77),

```c
/* Replace LOAD_CONST c1. LOAD_CONST c2 BINOP
   with    LOAD_CONST binop(c1,c2)
   The consts table must still be in list form so that the
   new constant can be appended.
   Called with codestr pointing to the first LOAD_CONST.
   Abandons the transformation if the folding fails (i.e.  1+'a').
   If the new constant is a sequence, only folds when the size
   is below a threshold value.  That keeps pyc files from
   becoming large in the presence of code like:  (None,)*1000.
*/
```

The actual evaluation of this particular code happens [in this block](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/648dcafa7e5f/Python/peephole.c#l124),

```c
    case BINARY_ADD:
        newconst = PyNumber_Add(v, w);
        break;
```

Comment: *+1* I guess [PyPy is doing](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/7ee4207de06dae02d9ac62b8d88223ae55729d7b/pypy/interpreter/astcompiler/optimize.py?at=default#cl-164) doing something similar as well. It's worth mentioning that `BINARY_DIVIDE` is an exception in Python 2(as explained in comments in PyPy's source code).

Answer (score 1):

The Python interpreter interprets from the inside out, that is, it reads the `1 + 1` evaluates it to `2`, *then* creates a function object that returns the constant `2` (notice the order here!).  Finally, the `dis` function evaluates. the newly created lambda function object, which simply returns a `2`.

Thus, the `1+1` has already been computed when the lambda function object is created, and the `dis.dis()` function knows nothing about the addition that took place when the interpreter read `1+1` and evaluated it to `2`.

If you do something like:

```
>>> dis.dis(lambda: x + 1)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 BINARY_ADD          
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

You'll notice that a BINARY_ADD instruction is used, since `x + 1` can't be further simplified by itself.

Comment: But the output of `dis.dis(compile('1+1', '', 'eval'))` is also `LOAD_CONST (2) RETURN_VALUE`. There is no inside out here, is there?

Comment: There's no interpreting here; it's a very simple compile-time optimization. As it stands, the answer implies something much more clever than what Python currently does.